# How to make java GC predictable?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Please see the attached screen shots of GC activities over a period of one hour.

Initially we see GC having large sawtooth pattern that recovers lot of heap memory.

Later the pattern changes to a smaller sawtooth pattern. At this point the memory starts growing slowly.

So, I manually triggered GC, which runs the Full GC and recovers most of  memory.

Once the memory recovers, again we notice the Large saw tooth pattern.

After sometime, the large sawtooth disappears and the small pattern reappears. Slowly memory grows. Once it reaches the threshold GC triggers.

Why GC pattern keeps changing?
How can we get a predictable GC?

This is G1GC on JDK 1.8
[image]
[image]

Comment: @apangin  I asked the question, because I am not able to find any answer so far. If I know, clearly, why would I come to SOF?

Comment: 1) I don't know.  2) It is (probably) complicated.  Hence ... Too Broad.  3) Understanding your case would require detailed analysis and observation of your application in action.  Making it too much work for a SO Q&A. 4) I don't think there is an easy fix to make GC more predictable ... in general. 5) Why does it matter what the curves look like?  Those low points do not mean that memory is actually released for something else in the system to use.

Comment: If you *really* need to know what is happening here because it *matters* to your application, I suggest that you contact Oracle and ask them to recommend a consultant who can help your tune the GC for your appllication.

Comment: Why do you think you want predictable GC?

Comment: GC uses adaptive algorithms; it's OK in general if the pattern changes - this is not the problem itself. Ask about the *real* problem instead, e.g. stop-the-world pauses, OOM errors, increased latency or anything else that causes application misfunction. Change in GC pattern *may* be an indicator of such a problem or may be *not* - we can't know without analyzing your application (which implies much work out of SO scope). At the very least, it's important to know JVM flags and see the detailed GC logs (`-XX:+PrintGCDetails`).

Comment: *"How can we get a predictable GC?"* - Use SerialGC with Xmx=Xms and AdaptiveSizePolicy disabled. But that's probably not what you want. Predictable does not mean good.

Comment: What's the underlying motivation/problem? A sawtooth pattern in itself is just a pattern, why do you need to change it?

Comment: GC logs FTW. Without that, you're stuck